# Firefox (not snap) looks different after install 22.04

Tags: 22.04, firefox, appearance

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 yesterday (Live usb on a Lenovo Thinkpad, dual-boot with Windows 10). Since the install, the appearance of websites in Firefox has changed: all content (google search, any website) looks as if it's been centred/moved to the right, whereas before everything was left-aligned.

I thought it was a snap-issue but I've since installed Firefox via the terminal (a non-snap) version and the issue persists. Websites still look as they previously did in Windows.

Any ideas how I could fix this? (about:fig?) I've tried finding a solution but no luck so far.

Comment: Seems like something to address with the Firefox people. Maybe report a bug to them.